# Force UI update on the fly, after changing current culture in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, internationalization

I need to support UI language change through the application menu.
The texts are localized using resource files (similar to approach 1 [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFUsingLocbaml.aspx#link_4))

if I set the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` before the ctor calls to `InitializeComponent()`, the UI is changed as it should.

However, if the `CurrentUICulture` is changed during the normal run of the application, the controls are not updated (i.e. the text remains the same, regardless of the current culture).

Is there a way to force the controls to refresh according the the `CurrentUICulture`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [the `ResourceDictionary` approach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613547%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) along with the `DynamicResourceMarkupExtension`. Using this approach you can swap out the resource dictionary representing the language the user has selected and the `DynamicResourceMarkupExtension` will ensure the new value is reflected in the UI.

Also, if you're willing to venture into the realm of a custom solution, there is the `LocalizeMarkupExtension` which is provided in [this WPF tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/LocalizeMarkupExtension.html).

Comment: Drew Marsh, the ResourceDictionary link is no longer valid. Can you point to the new link in .net 4.5?

Comment: The link seems to be valid. Title of page says "How to: Use a ResourceDictionary to Manage Localizable String Resources".

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the DataContext for the menu is an object that implements INotifyPropertyChanged, you can refresh all controls by specifying null (nothing) in the PropertyChanged event...

from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx):

> The PropertyChanged event can indicate
>   all properties on the object have
>   changed by using either a null
>   reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) or
>   String.Empty as the property name in
>   the PropertyChangedEventArgs.

Comment: Thanks. However, most of the UI are just static strings, and therefore without any DataContext.

Answer (score -1):

A way that I tried and works well is this method, to call after the assignment of the property in the ViewModel:

```
private void AllowUiToUpdate()
{
    var frame = new DispatcherFrame();

    var dispatcherOperationCallback = new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate
        {
            frame.Continue = false;
            return null;
        });

    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, dispatcherOperationCallback, null);

    Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this would work... could you elaborate further?